# FAST Protocol | Python wrapper

Tags: python, fast-protocol

Is there a good wrapper in Python to use [**FAST**](http://www.fixprotocol.org/fast) protocol to un-wrap the data coming from the stream-line. There's a implementation in Java (OpenFAST) but it has some performance issues that it cannot be used.

Thanks.

Comment: If Google doesn't know, then...

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Python wrapper for the FIX Protocol, [here](http://www.quickfixengine.org/).

A Python wrapper for the [FAST protocol(FIX Adapted for STreaming)](http://www.fixprotocol.org/fast) doesn't appear to have been created.

I would suggest downloading the [C files](http://www.fixprotocol.org/specifications/fastapi-1.0/docs/html/files.html) check out the [functions](http://www.fixprotocol.org/specifications/fastapi-1.0/docs/html/group__fastapi.html) then check out [the Python/C API docs](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/) and write a wrapper for the rest of the python community to enjoy!